# Show that $\sqrt{n}\overline{\mathbf{X}}\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

> Let $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_p)$ a sample of random vectors where each $X_i$ is
>   a random vector with $E[X_i]\sim \mu$ and $Var(X_i)\sim \Sigma$. Show that
>   $$\sqrt{n}\overline{\mathbf{X}}\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$$ where
>   $\mathbf{X}$ is a random matrix.

Here each $X_i$ is a random vector with $n$ components, then $X_1=(X_{11},X_{21},\dots,X_{n1})$. Then
$$
\overline{X}_i=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ji}
$$

If each $X_i$ is a random vector, then by the Central Limit Theorem
$$\overline{X_i}\sim N\Big(\mu,\frac{\Sigma}{n}\Big)\rightarrow \sqrt{n}\overline{X_i}\Big(\mu,\Sigma\Big)$$
Since each vector is Normal random variable, and the sum of Normal random variables too, then
$$E[\mathbf{\overline{X}}]=E[\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^p \overline{X_i}]=\mu$$

$$Var(\mathbf{\overline{X}})=Var\Big(\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^p \overline{X_i} \Big)=\frac{1}{p^2}Var\Big(\sum_{i=1}^p \overline{X_i}\Big)=\frac{1}{p}\Sigma$$
So
$$\mathbf{\overline{X}}\sim N_p(\mu,\frac{1}{p}\Sigma)\rightarrow \sqrt{n} \mathbf{\overline{X}}\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$$

Is this wrong?

Looks like I should proof the Multivariate Central Limit theorem, but I don't know if what I did proof anything.

Comment: I think you have to also assume that each $X_i$ are iid.. but nice question +1

Comment: What is $\bar X$?

Comment: @Jack is the sample mean

Comment: I don't understand your question. It seems that $\bar X$ depends also on the size of the sample. Notations are confusing.

Comment: Also, what is $\bar {X_{i}}$?

Comment: @Jack I made some edit, see if you understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be lots of confusion in  your question:

- It is unclear that what is the *dimension* of the random vectors and what is the *size* of your sample.
- The notation ${\bf X}$ and $\overline{\bf X}$ are *undefined*.
- $E[X_i]\sim\mu$ and $Var(X_i)\sim\Sigma$ are unjustified notations. I have never seen people use "$\sim$" sign this way.
- There is no limiting process at all in the notation $\sqrt{n}\overline{\mathbf{X}}\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$. As it stated, this means $\overline{X}$ has the normal distribution, which is wrong in general.

---

It seems that you are trying to state the $p$-dimensional Central Limit Theorem:

> Suppose $\{X_i\}$ is a *sequence* of *i.i.d.* random vectors of dimension $p$ such that for all $i$, 
>   $$
> E(X_i)=\mu,\quad Var(X_i)=\Sigma.
> $$
>   Define the "sample mean" of a sample with size $n$ as
>   $$
> \overline{X}_n:=\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}.
> $$
>   Then 
>   $
> \sqrt{n}\overline{X}_n
> $
>   *converges* in distribution to $N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$.

---

Any advanced probability theory textbook should contains a proof, if that is what you are looking for. See for instance Billingsley's *Probability and Measure*.

---

"Proof" is a noun, not a verb.

Comment: It would have been better if you do the proof yourself; other than refering to other stuff.. I got a comment from someone else saying the same thing, when i referred to wikipedia once.

Answer (score 1):

> **Theorem (CLT, the univariate case):** Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of iid random variables whose moment generating functions exist. Let $EX_i=\mu$ and $Var \, X_i =\sigma^2>$. Define $\bar{X}_n=(1/n) \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then the random variables defined by $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)/\sigma$ converge in distribution to $N(0,1)$.

The proof of this relies on the properties ofs, Let $M_X(t)=E(e^{tX})$ be the  moment generating function. These satisfy three properties that are important:
Using Taylor series, we can say
$$
M_X=1+tE(X)+\frac{t^2 E(X^2)}{2!}+\ldots.
$$
since the derivatives of MGFs are as follow
$$\frac{d^n}{dt^n}M_X(0)=E(X^n),$$
Let $Y_i=(X_i-\mu)/\sigma$ and $Y_n =\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i/\sqrt{n}$. Now using the fact that $M_{Y_1 + Y_2} = M_{Y_1}M_{Y_2}$, if $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, then
$$M_{Y_n} = M_{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i/\sqrt{n}} (t) =M_{\sum Y_i} (t/\sqrt{n})=M_{Y_1}(t/\sqrt{n})^n$$
Note that $M_{X_n}(t) \to M_X(t)$, then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$. Using Taylor 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} M_{Y_n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} M_{Y_1}(t/\sqrt{n})^n=\lim_{n \to \infty} [1+\frac{t^2}{2n}+o(t^2/n)]^n \to e^{t^2/2}.$$
due to $e^t=\lim_{n\to \infty} [1+t/n]^n$.

The Multivariate case is a straightforward generalization

Comment: The proof is the same for multivariate case? I just had to say that now the $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are random vectors normally distributed?

Comment: Yes, and you do the univariate proof, elementwise on the vectors

Comment: How I can show that if $M_{Y_n}(t)\rightarrow M_Y(t)$ then $Y_n\rightarrow^d Y$?